# Teclado android usa toda la pantalla en modo horizontal en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una Aplicacacion que necesito se use solo en modo `landscape` y resulta que que en un dispositivo ocupa toda la pantalla y en otro solo ocupa la mitad. necesito que solo se use la mitad ya que es incomodo tener que salir de la pantalla del teclado para pasar al siguiente campo
[image: Funciona bien en emulador con android 8.1]

[image: Ocupa toda la pantalla en dispositivo fisico]

Este es el código del xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilPrimerNombreRegTB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/titPrimerNombreRegTB"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
                    android:hint="Primer Nombre*:"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoComplete" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar dentro de `TextInputEditText` : `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` esto desabilitara
el modo de entrada en pantalla completa.